# How to remove gridlines from LiveCharts

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to remove the gridlines from a graph and only managed to remove the X axis seperator. I am using the LiveCharts package in a .NET framework 4.7.2 C# form. It is a stacked column chart from [LiveCharts](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/Wpf/Stacked%20Column) rotated 90°. All code I used is copied from there and edited to make things look a bit different. The main changes are that the seperator, the legend and the labels are removed. How can I remove them? I am very new to Visual Studio 2019, so I would appreciate a lot of explanation as I might not understand it otherwise.

Here is a screenshot for clarity:

[image: Screenshot of the graph in question]

Comment: Please provide more details. What library do you use?

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad, forgot to mention them. I added some details, is this enough or am I still missing something?

Comment: @Wicked Grinn, what is your kind of charts? How do you create it? Can you provide some code or steps to let me make a test?